# Pass value to Angular controller through ng-include

Tags: angularjs

From a server side code I am loading and angular template as follows:

```
<div ng-include="'/views/signup.html'" onload="init('premium')"></div>
```

The view is, for now, the following:

```
<form ng-controller="AccountSignupController as controller">
</form>
```

The controller is simply:

```
function AccountSignupController($scope) {

  $scope.plan = '';

  $scope.init = function (plan) {
    $scope.plan = plan;
    console.log(plan);
  };

};
```

On the console **plan** is always "undefined".

How can I pass a value to the controller through the template?

Do I need to set the controller on ng-include div and use ng-init?

Comment: I have onload. So is there any options to pass a parameter through ng-include?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `console.log(plan)`?

Comment: Yes, I just corrected. It was a mistake but I have it right on my code.

Comment: the init function is a function which lives on the controller - your "vanilla" javascript has no idea where it is

Comment: So the only option is to move ng-controller to the include div and use ng-init?

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the controller is inside the form where 'ng-controller' is. Thus $scope.init function is only "available" inside that form.

Both directives should be at the same level. Try moving 'ng-controller' to the div or 'ng-init' to the form (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating your controller using the `controller as binding` syntax. In that case properties and functions are bound to the `this` of your controller instead of `$scope`. Functions should be called using the binding.

Your template should be:

```
<div ng-include="'/views/signup.html'" 
   ng-controller="AccountSignupController as controller"
   onload="controller.init('premium')"></div>
```

Your controller:

```
function AccountSignupController() {

  var self = this;
  this.plan = '';

  this.init = function (initString) {
    self.plan = initString;
    console.log(initString);
  };
};
```

For more information on the `controller as binding` syntax, see the [AngularJS ngController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)